# ARCore Storing Anchor/HitTrackable positions and comparing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to make a simple function in the HelloARController script. In this script what I'm trying to do is store the position in which the Andy object is placed in the real world. I do this using this code in the Update() method:

```
storePos.Add(hit.Pose.position);
```

To my own understanding, hit.Pose.position is the 3D positioning of where the user taps the screen, relative to the real world space (I'm assuming. After some research I came to this conclusion. Please feel free to correct me!). So what I did was store those co-ordinates in a List. If the user were to hit or tap somewhere of the same co-ordinates again I just wanted to spawn a canvas. I do this by using a for loop to compare the hit position with the positions that were previously stored like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < storePos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (hit.Pose.position == storePos[i])
                        {
                            etc...
                        }
                    }
```

When trying out this code, it doesn't work and I've thought of some reasons as to why but struggling to find a solution to this problem. Whilst continuing to figure this out, I would appreciate some advice, answers or tips! :)

Comment: Well you are comparing 2 `Vector3` and expecting them to be same which will almost never occur. Because with touch it is almost impossible to touch same position. If you want to achieve this at least give each point a radius and if `hit.Pose.position` is in that radius do etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment this makes perfectly sense that your code is not working. Considering comparing two float values with `==` does not work due to precision of float values, comparing vector3s' with 3 floats would be impossible. In order to achieve this you can define a radius for each stored point and check if new touch is in the radius of any point like this:

```
float distance = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < storePos.Count; i++)
{
         distance = (hit.Pose.position - storePos[i]).magnitude;
         // 0.1 as radius
         if (distance < 0.1f )
         {
             etc...
         }
 }
```

Also if you would like to achieve something like tapping on Andy object and spawn the canvas, you can use `Raycasting` like this:

```
        Touch touch;
        if (!(Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began))
        {

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
            {                    
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject+" Object is hit");
            }

         }
```

Comment: I was actually thinking the exact same thing, but was having trouble on how to implement some sort of radius efficiently. The first segment of code you provided was a big help! Thank you :)